# Sorting versus hashing

Tags: sorting, hashing

My problem is as follows.  I have an array of `n` strings with `m < n` of them distinct.  I want to create a one-to-one function which assigns each of the `m` distinct strings to the numbers `0 ... m-1`.  For example, if my strings are:

`Bob, Amy, Bob, Charlie, Amy`

then the function:

`Bob -> 0, Amy -> 1, Charlie -> 2`

would meet my needs.  I have thought of three possible approaches:

1. Sort the list of strings, remove duplicates, and construct the function using a search algorithm.
2. Create a hash table and check each string to see if it is already in the table before inserting it.
3. Sort the list of strings, remove duplicates, and put the resulting list into a hash table.

My code will be written in Java, and I will likely use standard Java algorithms: merge sort for sorting, binary search for searching, and whatever the standard Java hash table algorithm is.

**Question:** Assume that after creating the function I will have to evaluate it on each of the n original strings.  Which of the three approaches is fastest?  Is there a better way?

Part of the problem is that I don't really know what's going on "under the hood" in standard hashing algorithms.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How big is `n` (& possibly `m`)?

Comment: It's safe to assume that n is at least 10000 but probably no larger than 100000.  I can't be sure about m, but it seems to typically be on the order of n/2.

Comment: Logically I'd expect sorting to be faster for shorter inputs, and hashing for longer inputs (at the cost of some memory), but I'm not sure where one would overtake the other. Sounds like a good case for doing a quick implementation of each and benchmarking.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: How tight is the `0 ... m-1 requirement`?  Could it be `0 .. n` with holes?  What are you using the numbers for?

Comment: @MichaelT: The numbers are indeed important.  The strings are labels for nodes in a network, and I'm trying to use a network analysis library which enumerates the nodes and manipulates them using their indices instead of their labels.  So I need some sort of dictionary between node labels and node indices.

Comment: If you really want to get exotic, speedwise, the trie's mentioned here may work well for detecting duplicates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I'll note that there are two different things to be concerned with. How long will it take to assign all the numbers, and how long will it take to lookup the number later.

### Sort the list of strings, remove duplicates, and construct the function using a search algorithm

Sorting will take O(n log n) time, you can remove the duplicate in O(n) time. To lookup the number you can use binary search which will take O(log m) time for each search.

### Create a hash table and check each string to see if it is already in the table before inserting it.

Hash table operations are typically considered to be O(1). This is a bit of lie because it depends on the number of collisions you get. But its close to O(1) and definitely better then O(log m). Checking and inserting all values will then be O(n). Fetching the counts later will be O(1) for each fetch.

### Sort the list of strings, remove duplicates, and put the resulting list into a hash table.

Sorting and deduplicating will take O(n log n) time. Inserting all of that into a hash will take O(m) time. Then fetching the individual elements will take O(1) time. This is basically the same as the previous option except that you spend O(n log n) extra time sorting.

The second option will be fastest, at least for large enough cases.

Comment: And for smaller cases, the choice probably won't matter, so the second option is still fine.

Comment: @Brian, yes, although I have found cases where attempts at optimizing by using a better big-O algorithm have considerably slowed the software. (In the case I'm thinking of, a priority queue with lots of items over time, but few at any one point in time).

Comment: You're right; the inefficiencies could add up if he runs this algorithm repeatedly.  I also like choice 2 for being simpler.  The OP intends to have a mapping from word to duplicate count; a `Dictionary` (or whatever equivalent class provided in the OP's language) would probably provide an already-written implementation for most of this functionality.

Comment: It sounds like choice 2 is the way to go - I'll use some sort of hash table.  Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: You use `O(m)` and `O(log m)` in several places where I think you mean `O(n)`. For example, I believe the lower bound on a sort operation would have to be `O(n log m)`, right?

Comment: @DanielPryden, it looks like I did m and n confused at times there. I've gone back and tried to correct. But I don't think its O(n log m). If we are sorting n items, the sort will be O(n log n).

Comment: @DanielPryden, but looking back, I'd have to say I errored in this answer. I didn't consider the case of a combined sort/deduplicate, and I didn't take into account the relatively bad cache locality of a hash.

Answer (score 1):

The way I like to tackle this is coarse hash with buckets and sort and remove duplicates in parallel. This is for inputs of a sufficient scale to benefit from all of this and multithreading (say at least tens of thousands but perhaps more in the range of hundreds of thousands to millions on average). Otherwise this technique will tend to add more work than it saves.

By coarse hash, I mean, say, make 64 resizable random-access sequences.

```
sequence buckets[64]
```

Then for each string, just examine the first character and put it in the right bucket.

```
for each string:
    buckets[string[0] % 64].append(string)
```

Then with a parallel for loop, sort each bucket and remove duplicates.

```
parallel for each bucket:
    sort(bucket)
    unique(bucket)
```

It's an easy way to parallelize many operations with this first "coarse hashing" step. In this case, with the "coarse hashing", you actually want many collisions to fill up the buckets to process in parallel, and ideally in a way where there's a reasonably even distribution of collisions per bucket.

Ideally you also construct a list of references/pointers to buckets which aren't empty prior to processing them in parallel, since it'd be a waste to grab a thread from the thread pool just to process an empty bucket. You could also hash in parallel to remove duplicates but typically I find it easier and less fiddly to achieve better results with sorting for each bucket. Otherwise the threads can end up allocating a whole lot of memory.

Now if you want to get fancy, let's say the first step didn't evenly distribute the elements into buckets so well, so one thread encounters a bucket with like a million elements in it. In that case you can repeat the step again in that thread/bucket and coarse hash the element using the second character as key and then recursively sort/unique those sub-buckets in parallel.

Some benchmarks:

```
Sorting 10000000 elements 3 times...

mt_sort_int: {0.135 secs}
-- small result: [ 12 17 17 22 52 55 67 73 75 87 ]

mt_sort: {0.445 secs}
-- small result: [ 12 17 17 22 52 55 67 73 75 87 ]

mt_radix_sort: {0.228 secs}
-- small result: [ 12 17 17 22 52 55 67 73 75 87 ]

std::sort: {1.697 secs}
-- small result: [ 12 17 17 22 52 55 67 73 75 87 ]

qsort: {2.610 secs}
-- small result: [ 12 17 17 22 52 55 67 73 75 87 ]
```

`mt_sort`, `mt_radix_sort`, and `mt_sort_int` above uses the technique described above (though with a lot more fluff to be used in production like special cases to handle inputs of different sizes) minus the linear pass to eliminate consecutive duplicates (trivial processing). The only differences between the three is the sorting algorithm they use (`mt_sort` and `mt_radix_sort` use linear-time sorts, `mt_sort` uses linearithmic). The differences get more and more pronounced the larger the input size with the fastest `mt_*` versions being even faster proportionally and the slower ones from the C and C++ standard library (`qsort` and `std::sort`) being even slower relatively.

The only comparison-based sort I know out there that rivals `mt_sort` is Intel's parallel sort from Thread Building Blocks which outperforms `mt_sort` in some cases while `mt_sort` outperforms it in others (pretty neck-to-neck).

If you want to just filter out duplicates for the purposes of interning (mapping a unique index to each unique string), you can do this in a fraction of the time of the benchmarks above, since most of the time spent in `mt_sort`, `mt_radix_sort`, and `mt_sort_int` isn't partitioning elements into buckets and then sorting the buckets in parallel (`qsort` and `std::sort` don't need this step since they're single-threaded sorts that don't bother with buckets). It's merging the results of the buckets into one giant sorted list. When you just want to filter out duplicates, you don't need that elaborate merge step between the buckets.

> Part of the problem is that I don't really know what's going on "under
>   the hood" in standard hashing algorithms. Any help would be
>   appreciated.

I don't know for sure either but I think most of them use open addressing and possibly just linear probing since it lends itself well to cache hits.

I actually find more use out of hash tables with separate chaining that never allocate more buckets than the user requests which makes the memory use of the entire table perfectly predictable (4 bytes per bucket + 8 bytes per element inserted) but the trick to making them reasonable competitors against open addressing is to avoid heap allocations per node and just linking up nodes through indices, like so:

[image]

... with the node indices doubling over as either an index to the next used node in the bucket or the next free node to reclaim upon subsequent intersections if the node was removed. Spatial locality can degrade with this technique but making a copy of the hash table then makes each neighbor in a bucket perfectly contiguous if your use case can afford an "optimization" pass from time to time to improve locality of reference.

I tend to beat things like `unordered_map` in C++ using the above technique, though theoretically the optimal efficiency probably lies with `unordered_map` if you can get the hashing just right. Where I like mine better is that I don't have to put that much thought into the hashing and get something very reasonable and it also doesn't explode in memory use behind my back. I know exactly how much memory it will take upfront just based on how many buckets I request and how many elements I insert.